# Yahoo Pipes - Sort items, or pick only a limited number per source; is that possible?

Tags: regex, rss, pipe, yahoo, feed

I've merged several RSS feeds into one, the problem is one of them puts out way too many items, thereby "burying" the others.

Is it possible to either

- limit the number of items per feed source (!) per day/hour

or

- define that each feed will get at least one item of the day on top?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Yahoo pipes but you could do the "at least one item" rule by (for each feed) splitting and handling the first item of the feed and the rest of it separately and then combining it after limiting the "rest"/ends of the feeds/combinations of those.